# MVC4 + ServiceStack +....Glimpse?

Tags: servicestack, glimpse

I'm running ServiceStack v4 under `/api` in my MVC4 application. I'd like to have [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) profile my SQL queries.  My SQL tab is disabled in the HUD.

[image: SQL tab disabled in Glimpse HUD]

Any idea how to configure this?

Comment: How are you doing your data access?

Comment: Using the ServiceStack OrmLite with MS Sql backend.

Comment: Looks like you found the solution. Was going to point you in the direction of the Manual Integration docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I chose was to override the `SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.CreateDbConnection()`similar to [this solution](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/wiki/Manual-ADO-Integration).

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
                "<connection string>",
                SqlServerWithGlimpseDialectProvider.Instance);


public class SqlServerWithGlimpseDialectProvider 
    : SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider
{
    public new static SqlServerWithGlimpseDialectProvider Instance = new SqlServerWithGlimpseDialectProvider();

    public override IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString, Dictionary<string, string> options)
    {
        return new GlimpseDbConnection(
            base.CreateConnection(connectionString, options) as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection);
    }
}
```

SQL now profiling:

[image]

Comment: How do you catch service requests with glimpse? In my setup is only possible to see requests for http:/localhost:1234/metadata, but the service calls are not caught by glimpse.

Comment: Your service must be hosted in the ASP.net pipeline for glimpse to see it I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no ServiceStack expert, but there are docs for getting it setup. Have you tried following [these instructions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks#setting-up-glimpse)?

Comment: This is looks it's just profiling the service methods, not the data access.